# element.removeEventListener('mousedown', externalFunction, useCapture); is not working

Tags: javascript

I need to first remove the event listener before dynamically adding more elements which also need the same event listener. I am using an external function name (not an anonymous function) and specifying the same useCapture value in both the add and remove.

The function is nested within another function. ***< suspected problem was the problem***

You can see the problem by clicking the first "add button"  more than once. The first click adds one more button, the second click adds two more, the third click adds four more, etc. Each click should only add one more. I guess the return value of `removeEventListener` is always `undefined` so I can only tell that removal did not work from the duplicate events.

```js
var app = function() {
 console.log('app');
 
 var setup = function() {
  console.log('setup');
 
  var addButton = function(e) {
   console.log(e);
   var button = e.target;
   var newButton = document.createElement('BUTTON');
   newButton.innerText = 'add another button';
   button.parentNode.appendChild( newButton );
   setup();
  }
 
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  
  for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
   var button = buttons[i];
   button.removeEventListener('mousedown', addButton, false);
   button.addEventListener('mousedown', addButton, false);
  }
  
 }
 setup();
}
app();
```

```html
<div>
 <button>add button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did that `button` variable come from in the `addButton` function?

Comment: good catch, that would be the event target. updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

Removing the addButton function from the nest fixed the problem.

Also, defining `app.addButton` within `app.setup` or within the nest causes `app.addButton` to be overwritten each time `app.setup` is called which destroys the reference needed for removeEventListener. So the name alone is not all that matters. It  must be the original function, not an exact copy.

```js
var app = {};

app.addButton = function(e) {
 console.log(e);
 var button = e.target;
 var newButton = document.createElement('BUTTON');
 newButton.innerText = 'add another button';
 button.parentNode.appendChild( newButton );
 app.setup();
}

app.setup = function() {
 console.log('setup');

 var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

 for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  button.removeEventListener('mousedown', app.addButton, false);
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', app.addButton, false);
 }
}

app.init = function() {
 console.log('app');
 app.setup();
}

app.init();
```

```html
<div>
  <button>add button</button>
</div>
```